# How does sqoop determine what to put in $CONDITIONS

Tags: sqoop

I am looking at some existing code written in sqoop. I can see queries like

```
select * from table where $CONDITIONS
```

This code works and sqoop is pulling data only for a specific date range.

This is good, but how does sqoop know which column in the table it has to apply the date range filter (if the table in question has multiple date time columns).

Comment: you are specifying column name (_`id` in your question_).

Comment: ignore the id, how does the $CONDITION know which date column to use.

Comment: check my [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37048390/3929393) answer related to this.