# Sqoop --split-by error while importing despite of having primary key in table

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, hadoop2, cloudera-quickstart-vm

**MySQL table with dept_id as primary key**

```
|dept_id | dept_name |  
| 2 | Fitness   
| 3 | Footwear  
| 4 | Apparel   
| 5 | Golf      
| 6 | Outdoors  
| 7 | Fan Shop
```

**Sqoop Query**

```
sqoop import \  
-m 2 \  
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \  
--username retail_dba \  
-P \  
--query 'select * from departments where dept_id < 6  AND $CONDITIONS' \      
--target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/departments;
```

**Results with an error on console:**

> When importing query results in parallel, you must specify `--split-by`

**---Question point!---**
Even though the table has primary key & the splits can be equally distributed between 2 mappers then what is the need of **--spit-by** or **-m 1** ??

Guide me for the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not primary key with `--split-by` usage. you are seeing error because of use of `--query` option. This option ***MUST*** be used with `--split-by`, `--target-dir` and `$CONDITIONS` in query.

[free_form_query_imports documentations](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports)

> When importing a free-form query, you must specify a destination
>   directory with --target-dir.
>
> If you want to import the results of a query in parallel, then each
>   map task will need to execute a copy of the query, with results
>   partitioned by bounding conditions inferred by Sqoop. Your query must
>   include the token $CONDITIONS which each Sqoop process will replace
>   with a unique condition expression. You must also select a splitting
>   column with --split-by.

You can use `--where` option if you don't want to use `--split-by` and `--query`:

```
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  -P \
  --table departments \
  --target-dir /user/cloudera/departments \
  -m 2 \
  --where "department_id < 6"
```

if you use `--boundary-query` option then you don't need `--split-by`, `--query` option:

```
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  -P \
  --table departments \
  --target-dir /user/cloudera/departments \
  -m 2 \
  --boundary-query "select 2, 6 from departments limit 1"
```

[selecting_the_data_to_import](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import)

> By default sqoop will use query `select min(<split-by>),
>   max(<split-by>) from <table name>` to find out boundaries for creating
>   splits. In some cases this query is not the most optimal so you can
>   specify any arbitrary query returning two numeric columns using
>   --boundary-query argument.

Comment: adding already answered answer with more **fancy** (_irrelevant to question_) details. Let me know if you want more upvotes or bounty..:D

Comment: @devツ - Thanks - any feedback is welcome and appreciated. When I read your answer it was directing to drills documents and did not specifically explaining required options for `--query` parameter. I added additional options as alternative options in context to `--split-by` and `--query` options, so user can see difference that not using `--split-by` with primary-keyed table import and mapper > 1 actually possible with these options(I found it relevant - in my opinion)  - thanks again :)

Comment: BTW drill was a typo which I fixed, docs are referring to the same sqoop docs.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Sqoop import needs --split-by when you use --query is because when you specify the source location of data in "query", it is not possible to know/guess the primary key for Sqoop. Because, in query, you can join two or more tables which will have multiple keys and fields. So, Sqoop can't know/guess on which of those keys can it split by.

Answer (score 0):

As per sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports),

> If you want to import the results of a query in parallel, then each map task will need to execute a copy of the query, with results partitioned by bounding conditions inferred by Sqoop. Your query must include the token $CONDITIONS which each Sqoop process will replace with a unique condition expression. You must also select a splitting column with --split-by.

So you have to specify your **primary key** in `--split-by` tag.

If you choose 1 mapper, Sqoop will not split task in parallel and perform complete import in 1 mapper.

Check my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048390/3929393) (*if you want*) to understand need of `$CONDITIONS` and number of mappers.