# Sqoop is working only with 1 map task ( - m 1) not more ,

Tags: mysql, sqoop

My Sqoop import is working only with 1 map task ( - m 1) not more.

This is working:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseY --username root --password PASSWORD --table tableX --target-dir /tmp/databaseY --as-textfile -m 1
```

This not:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseY --username root --password PASSWORD --table tableX --target-dir /tmp/databaseY --as-textfile -m 3
```

My cluster is a 3 nodes on AWS.

I missed something during the configuration?

----EDIT FOR THE SOLUTION ----
The problem was the localhost. I changed it by the IP address and it is working fine.

Comment: does source table has PK?

Comment: both the commands are same. Please modify your question.

Comment: Dev: It is modified. The -m at the end is not the same now. BigDataLearner: The source table should be OK as it is an official test exemple table.

Answer (score 1):

As sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism) are sufficient to put some light on this,

> When performing parallel imports, Sqoop needs a criterion by which it can split the workload. Sqoop uses a **splitting column** to split the workload. By default, **Sqoop will identify the primary key column (if present) in a table and use it as the splitting column.** The low and high values for the splitting column are retrieved from the database, and the map tasks operate on evenly-sized components of the total range. For example, if you had a table with a primary key column of id whose minimum value was 0 and maximum value was 1000, and Sqoop was directed to use 4 tasks, Sqoop would run four processes which each execute SQL statements of the form `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id >= lo AND id < hi`, with (lo, hi) set to (0, 250), (250, 500), (500, 750), and (750, 1001) in the different tasks.

---

> If a table does not have a primary key defined and the `--split-by <col>`is not provided, then import will fail unless the number of mappers is explicitly set to one with the `--num-mappers 1` option.

*(Emphasis is mine)*

**Edit:** My previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048390/3929393) on a related topic will also help you on this.