# Significance of $conditions in Sqoop

Tags: sqoop

What is the significance of $conditions clause in sqoop import command?

```
select col1, col2 from test_table where \$CONDITIONS
```

Comment: refer:https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import

Comment: already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42331952/3929393 Let me know if you have any follow up question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sqoop performs highly efficient data transfers by inheriting Hadoop’s parallelism.

- To help Sqoop split your query into multiple chunks that can be
  transferred in parallel, you
     need to include the $CONDITIONS placeholder in the where clause of your query.
- Sqoop
        will automatically substitute this placeholder with the generated conditions specifying
        which slice of data should be transferred by each individual task.
- While you could skip
        $CONDITIONS by forcing Sqoop to run only one job using the --num-mappers 1 param‐
        eter, such a limitation would have a severe performance impact.

For example:-

> If you run a parallel import, the map tasks will execute your query
>   with different values substituted in for $CONDITIONS. one mapper
>   may execute "select bla from foo WHERE (id >=0 AND id < 10000)", and
>   the next mapper may execute "select bla from foo WHERE (id >= 10000
>   AND id < 20000)" and so on.