# Can we have two sql queries in the query parameter of the sqoop import command

Tags: hive, sqoop

I'm trying to import two tables from RDBMS to Hive. Is there any possibility to fire two sql queries in the --query parameter of the sqoop import command.

Currently, I'm able to sqoop the table using one sql query using the below command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://192.168.xx.xx/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=ds_tbl_db 
--driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver 
--username dbc 
--password dbc 
--query 'select * from table' 
--hive-import 
--hive-table reason_hive 
--target-dir <hdfs-location> 
-m 1
```

Comment: Do you want to store output of both SQL queries in different hive tables?

Comment: Yes. I want to store both the outputs in different hive tables. Is there any approach to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use two SQL in `--query` argument to store output in two different Hive Tables.

You have to do it one by one.

**EDIT:**

You can't fully rely on sqoop for performing SQL queries. Join queries are supported via Sqoop. But only simple queries are **recommended**.

Sqoop expects `WHERE $CONDITIONS` in the end of the sql queries. It is replaced by sqoop to perform range queries so that multiple mappers can run SQL queries in parallel. Check my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048390/3929393) for details.

Sample query :

```
--query "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE \$CONDITIONS"
```

Add `-verbose` in your sqoop command to see query fired by sqoop for bebug.

Comment: Ok. Can I use joins in the --query argument? Or will it lead to ambiguous results as per this link http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal

Comment: @dev333 Happy to help..:)